# Finding the kernel of a linear transformation given its action on a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $f: U\rightarrow V$ be linear transformation and let $\{u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}\}$ be basis of $U$ and let $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ be basis of $V$.

Knowing that:

$f(u_{1})=2v_{1}$

$f(u_{2})=-v_{2}$

$f(u_{1}+u_{3})=v_{1}+v_{2}$

$f(u_{1}-u_{3})=3v_{1}-v_{2}$

Find $\ker f$ and its basis.

I will be glad for any tips. I am stuck just from the beginning and do not know how to do this.

Comment: What is $f(u_1+u_3)-f(u_1-u_3)$? (hint use linearity).

Comment: Is there a mistake? since from 1st and 3rd equality we have $f(u_3)=v_2$

Comment: The third and fourth equations give $f(u_1+u_3)+f(u_1-u_3) = f(2u_1)=4v_1$, so $f(u_1)=2v_1$, which seems to contradict the first equation!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Sorry I made stupid while rewriting.

Comment: Now the 4th equality is unnecessary.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Unnecessary but for 100% it is written in my exercise.

Comment: @DanielRust so I write $f(u_{1}+u_{3})-f(u_{1}-u_{3})=2f(u_{3})$ And then I see that $f(u_{3})=v_{2} - v_{1}$ Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

First find a combination of the given values that will allow you to find $f(u_3)$, which was not given explicitly. Now check that the final equation tells you something that you already knew, so ignore it.

Then write out the equation saying that $au_1+bu_2+cu_3$ is in the kernel of $f$, namely $f(au_1+bu_2+cu_3)=0$, using linearity of $f$ and the given values. Then use that the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent, so that the linear combination of them you will have equated to zero implies all its coefficients are zero. Finally solve the system of linear equations so obtained for the scalars $a,b,c$, and write a general solution as a combination of some specific solutions (the parameters in your solution become the coefficients of this combination).

Once you get the hang of this, you will discover that all the operations needed to find the solution can be easily done in terms of the coefficients occurring in the expressions for $f(u_1)$, $f(u_2)$ and $f(u_3)$ in terms of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, combined into a matrix form.

Comment: So I have: $f(u_{1})=2v_{1}, f(u_{2})=-v_{2}, f(u_{3})=v_{2}-v_{1}$ And than as you say I write $f(au_1+bu_2+cu_3)=0$ And so I write $a \cdot f(u_1)+b \cdot f(u_2) +c \cdot f(u_3)=0$ ,then I use some of my equations $(2a) \cdot v_{1} - b \cdot v_{2} + c \cdot (v_{2}-v_{1})  = 0$ I do not understand what would be the Ker? Could you elaborate on this a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $u_1,...,u_n$ is a basis of $U$ and $f(u_i)=w_i$. The you can find the kernel of $f$ by:

1. Finding the set of solutions $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,...,x_n]$ of $x_1w_1+...+x_nw_n=0$
2. Using these solutions to compute $x_1u_1+...+x_nu_n$. These are the vectors of the kernel.